# Differences between forms of LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql

What is the difference between these query

```sql
SELECT
    A.AnyField
FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.AId = A.Id
    LEFT JOIN C ON B.CId = C.Id
```

and this another query

```sql
SELECT
    A.AnyField
FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        B
        JOIN C ON B.CId = C.Id
    ) ON B.AId = A.Id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original answer:

They are not the same.

For example `a left join b left join c` will return a rows, plus b rows even if there are no c rows.

`a left join (b join c)` will never return b rows if there are no c rows.

Added later:

```
SQL>create table a (id int); 
SQL>create table b (id int);
SQL>create table c (id int);
SQL>insert into a values (1);
SQL>insert into a values (2);
SQL>insert into b values (1);
SQL>insert into b values (1);
SQL>insert into c values (2);
SQL>insert into c values (2);
SQL>insert into c values (2);
SQL>insert into c values (2);
SQL>select a.id from a left join b on a.id = b.id left join c on b.id = c.id;
         id
===========
          1
          1
          2

                  3 rows found

SQL>select a.id from a left join (b join c on b.id = c.id) on a.id = b.id;
         id
===========
          1
          2

                  2 rows found
```

Answer (score 2):

The first query is going to take ALL records from table `a` and then only records from table `b` where `a.id` is equal to `b.id`. Then it's going to take all records from table `c` where the resulting records in table `b` have a `cid` that matches `c.id`.

The second query is going to first JOIN `b` and `c` on the `id`. That is, records will only make it to the resultset from that join where the `b.CId` and the `c.ID` are the same, because it's an `INNER JOIN`.

Then the result of the `b INNER JOIN c` will be LEFT JOINed to table `a`. That is, the DB will take all records from `a` and only the records from the results of `b INNER JOIN c` where `a.id` is equal to `b.id`

The difference is that you may end up with more data from `b` in your first query since the DB isn't dropping records from your result set just because `b.cid <> c.id`.

For a visual, the following Venn diagram shows which records are available

[image]

Comment: In the OP, only columns from `A` are selected so the query results will be identical

Comment: It's not necessarily true that you get the same number of records.  Consider a row in `A` that has two matching rows in `B`, with no matching rows in `C`. The first version of the query would produce two rows in this case, whereas the second version would produce only one.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    A.AnyField
FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.AId = A.Id
    LEFT JOIN C ON B.CId = C.Id
```

In this query you are LEFT JOINing C with B which will give you all records possible with B whether or not there is a match to any records in C.

```
SELECT
    A.AnyField
FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        B
        JOIN C ON B.CId = C.Id
    ) ON B.AId = A.Id
```

In this query you are INNER JOINing C with B which will result in matching B and C records.

Both queries will give you the same result set as you are only pulling records from A so you will not see what records had matches and what did not in regards to B and C.